# Child element being returned with parentNode

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm currently using Vue 3.0 and Element+ to build a website, and I'm coming across an inconsistency.

I have a div being displayed on a page (an array of objects) and I'm trying to make it so I can remove the object from the array when a button is clicked. Everything renders fine, but for some reason, sometimes when the Delete button is clicked, it returns the button element instead of the parent element, and since the button has no ID it becomes null. I haven't been able to discern a pattern to it. In the end, the goal is to read the ID of the div element and use that in a function to filter out the object represented by the div that is clicked.

Why is the parentNode sometimes returning the child element of the parentNode instead of the parent element?

EDIT: I changed the code to make it into a card instead of just a div, and it appears that it's not returning the element clicked on, but the child element of the parentNode.

Vue Code:

```
<div
  v-for="section in sections"
  :key="section.id"
  class="section"
  :id="section.id">
  <h4>{{ section.title }}</h4>
  <p>{{ section.description }}</p>
  <el-button type="danger" @click="deleteSection">Delete Section</el-button>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
 deleteSection(element) {
  const sectionID = element.target.parentNode;
  console.log(sectionID);
},
```

Console log:

```
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"2">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <button class=​"el-button el-button--danger" type=​"button">​…​</button>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"0">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <button class=​"el-button el-button--danger" type=​"button">​…​</button>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"1">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"1">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"1">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <button class=​"el-button el-button--danger" type=​"button">​…​</button>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <button class=​"el-button el-button--danger" type=​"button">​…​</button>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"1">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"2">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"2">​…​</div>​
NewGoal.vue?e7de:50 <div class=​"section" id=​"0">​…​</div>​
```

Comment: Why do you directly need to modify the DOM to delete a section though? Couldn't you just do `sections.splice(idx, 1)` on `onClick` of button? The idx will be passed from `v-for="(section, idx) in sections"` and button click will have `<el-button type="danger" @click="deleteSection(idx)">Delete Section</el-button>`. Vue automatically deletes the element from DOM if you remove your section from sections array.

Comment: So, I'm not using the DOM to delete the section. I'm storing an ID of the section in a parentNode of the el-card. The reason I'm not using the index is because the next step would be to make each section drag and drop, meaning the index will change for each section. I am fairly new to things, but for some reason, in my head, using the index won't work because of the moving around of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this out. It looks like it's a bug with Element+, or at least an issue with Element+, since what's happening doesn't happen with a regular HTML button.

Looking at the code for el-button, there is a v-if statement that appears to add a slot. Unfortunately, I can't tell what it's adding or how to make it do it consistently.

EDIT: Whoops! I should have used event.currentTarget, and not eventTarget.target. Changing that fixes the issue.